# Need help in my query scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help in writing a query for the below data (SecondaryTable),

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID1     PrimaryID2     TableID     FlagField     ServiceID     FieldData
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PID11          PID21          1             1             6             ABC
PID11          PID21          2             0             6             DEF
PID11          PID21          3             1             7             ABC
PID11          PID21          4             0             7             DEF 
PID11          PID21          5             0             8             ABC
PID11          PID21          6             0             8             DEF 
PID11          PID21          7             1             9             ABC
PID11          PID21          8             0             9             DEF
```

I need to write a query to in which I am joining it with the table (MainTable) that has the granularity level of "PrimaryID1" and "PrimaryID2", the requirement is like this for the combination of "PrimaryID1" and "PrimaryID2" if the table has "FlagField" = 1 for any one of the "ServiceID" of (6,7,8,9) then that field needs to be marked as "1".

This is how I have implmeneted now,

```
SELECT
      MT.PrimaryID1,
      MT.PrimaryID2,
      CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 ST.FieldID
                 FROM SecondaryTable
                 WHERE ServiceID IN (6,7,8,9) AND 
                       ST.PrimaryID1 = MT.PrimaryID1 AND
                       ST.PrimaryID2 = MT.PrimaryID2) IS NULL
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1
      END AS SecondaryTableFlag

FROM  MainTable MT
```

I know that if the top 1 comes as '0' then I am screwed, I even thought of having an order by in the correlated query but that won't work (obviously!!). Need to know if there is any alternative method for this one.

In this above case of data for "SecondaryTable" this should be my output, but I am not sure about my above query

```
-------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID1     PrimaryID2    SecondaryTableFlag
-------------------------------------------------
PID11          PID21         1
```

Comment: can you please your output also @padmaprakash

Comment: Remember that comparing any value to NULL using the `=` operator will always result in FALSE. If you want to check whether a value is NULL, write `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you describe it step by step? you want to combine Id1 and Id2 when what?

Comment: @mohan111 I have added a sample output !! hope this helps !!

Comment: @Dan sure i would use IS NULL going forward !!

Comment: Guys !! Is NULL is not the issue but i just need an alternate approach for the query !! Thats what all I need !! We have eight records in the sample data for in which "FlagField" is 1 in more than occasion for ServiceIDs of (6,7,8,9) if that is the case then the "SecondaryTableFlag" needs to be 1 if not 0. I hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for this situation taught me some thing that some times we have to think simple instead of thinking too complicated. Just changed TOP 1 with MAX() function.

```
ANSWER
    SELECT
          MT.PrimaryID1,
          MT.PrimaryID2,
          (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ST.FieldID),0)
           FROM SecondaryTable
           WHERE ServiceID IN (6,7,8,9) AND 
                 ST.PrimaryID1 = MT.PrimaryID1 AND
                 ST.PrimaryID2 = MT.PrimaryID2) 
           AS SecondaryTableFlag

    FROM  MainTable MT
```